# unable to load_dynamic a library in python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using a third party Python API, which imports a library. Here is the directory layout:

```
myproject
  |
  |--src
  |   |
  |   |--mycode.py
  |
  |--3rdparty
      |
      |--aardvark_py.py
      |--aardvark.dll
      |--aardvark.so
```

`aardvak_py.py`contains the following code:

```
try:
    import aardvark as api
except ImportError, ex1:
    import imp, platform
    ext = platform.system() in ('Windows', 'Microsoft') and '.dll' or '.so'
    try:
        api = imp.load_dynamic('aardvark', 'aardvark' + ext)
    except ImportError, ex2:
        import_err_msg  = 'Error importing aardvark%s\n' % ext
        import_err_msg += '  Architecture of aardvark%s may be wrong\n' % ext
        import_err_msg += '%s\n%s' % (ex1, ex2)
        raise ImportError(import_err_msg)
```

`mycode.py` contains the following code:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),
                   '..', '3rdparty'))

import aardvark
```

For some reason when I run my code the exception is triggered. However if I move `aardvark.dll` in the same directory where `mycode.py` is, everything works fine. Can someone explain why this is happening and is there a way to keep a `.dll` in the other directory without moving it?

Answer (score 0):

Install 64-bit python, it seems to be an undocumented requirement for Aardvark.